# Web API XML Documentation from Linq-to-Sql Models (DB First)

Tags: linq-to-sql, documentation, asp.net-web-api, xml-documentation

I am using web API to provide some web services.

There is a linq to sql `datacontext`  which is auto-generated from database and I use it in my API methods.
Now for documenting, I need to add XML comments to the classes and the properties and methods of them, from the auto-genereated `datacontext.designer.cs`

When I open up the `.designer.cs` file and force add my XML comments to it, it works and showed up in the documentation section of the website. But as you know, it is auto generated file, and when I change the model, all my comments will disappear.

what can I do to solve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a partial class (in a different file) for the class defined in the `designer.cs file` and move the property you want to change the XML comments from the `designer.cs file` to your newly created class. Then add the appropriate comments and they will stay there, no matter how many times the auto generated one is recreated.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but are you sure to **move** the property! I'm afraid it would generate again as soon as I change the model. let me see...

Comment: Not the way I wanted! , I add a partial class for one class of the .dbml model. then I was able to add XML comment to the class itself but not the properties. as you know, I couldn't add the same properties to the partial class because it can't be duplicated properties.

Comment: I need to add XML comment to each property of a linq-to-sql generated class. How to do that?

Comment: Right, you have to *move* the property definition from the auto-generated file to your newly created one.

Comment: I want to have the auto-generation utility, because I am adding other classes over time. so I can't ignore it. there must be a way!?